# Sorting an array with jQuery JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I was trying to figure out how to sort an array provided by a php script. The php script gets the html files in a directory, and then passes them to jQuery, which then fetches them and displays them on the page. This is what I have:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('helper.php', function(data) {
     var items = [];
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       $.get("articles/" + val, function(html){
             $("#postdata").append(html);
           }, 'html');
     });
   });
 });
</script>
```

How do I sort (or reverse) sort them? The filenames have the format {S}-post-slug.html, where {S} is the number of seconds after the epoch. I want to be able to display them with the latest file first.

Comment: It's probably easier to do this on the php-side.  Is that an option?

Comment: @JakeFeasel I've tried, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking. http://phpjs.org/functions/ksort:460

pretty much how php ksort works.

Comment: ksort doesn't work, I tried to use ksort but for some reason jQuery ignored it and sorted it the same way. I also tried krsort, asort and arsort.

Answer (score 0):

This is not particularly easy because you have N asynchronous `$.get()` operations proceeding in parallel and each finishing at unknown times.  The only options I can think of are:

1. Hold all the data in an array and sort the array before inserting anything and then insert them in the sorted order.  This has the disadvantage that no data will appear in the page until all the data has been retrieved.
2. As the articles arrive, insert each one in the proper order.  This is probably the best user experience, but the most code to write.
3. Insert all the articles and then when the last one is done, sort them in the DOM.  This shows content as it arrives, but then moves it all around.  This is probably the least desirable.

Here's a way to insert each article in order as they arrive (they can arrive in any order) which I think is the best user experience.  Articles will appear in order as they arrive:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON('helper.php', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        $.get("articles/" + val, function(html){

            // parse the article time out of the filename
            var time = 0;
            var matches = val.match(/\d+/);
            if (matches) {
                time = parseInt(matches, 10);
            }

            // create new article and tag it with an identifying class
            // and the filename time
            var o = $(html);
            o.data("ftime", time);
            o.addClass("timedArticle");

            // now find where to insert this article (newest articles first)
            // by finding the first article whose time is less than the 
            // time of the article to insert
            var target;
            $("#postdata").children(".timedArticle").each(function() {
                if ($(this).data("ftime") < time) {
                    target = this;
                    return(false);
                }
            });
            if (target) {
                o.insertBefore(target);
            } else {
                $("#postdata").append(o);
            }
        }, 'html');
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: I tried this, it still printed the same order, even after I tried sorting it with arsort, asort, krsort, and ksort. Shouldn't jQuery follow the rules? The PHP script gives me `{"1":"1323289297-second-post.html","0":"1323281691-hello-world.html"}` with `arsort` and `["1323281691-hello-world.html","1323289297-second-post.html"]` with `asort`. Something's up with it, because it's not assigning specific key values with asort. What's going on?

Comment: @jibcage - I have no idea why you're asking me about PHP sorting as that is not one of the solutions I recommended or wrote about in my answer.  I wrote a client-side javascript solution that will insert the articles in filename order with the most recent first regardless of what order they are listed in in the JSON.  Sorting on the server will NOT reliably solve the problem as you're requesting the articles asynchronously and they can arrive in a different order than you requested them.

Comment: I didn't intend to make it about PHP, I was saying that it might be a PHP problem since it's not sorting in the correct order no matter what. Your script works just fine, it's the backend that's the issue :)

Comment: @jibcage - FYI, I updated my script.  You said in your question that the filenames looked like this `{S}-post-slug.html`, but they are actually like `"1323289297-second-post.html"` so I modified my script to handle the actual filenames.  I would suggest you try that fix as it may have been keeping the filename parsing from working.  Keep in mind that this script works regardless of the order from the server.  You do not need to sort on the server for this script to work.

Comment: excellent, that fixed it. thanks! sorry if I was ambiguous about the filename, I was trying to clarify what the numbers meant. :)

Comment: out of curiosity, how would you fix this if the filename was something along the lines of `2011-06-23-second-post.html` ?

Comment: He didn't need to parse the numbers out. He could have just compared the filenames and it would have worked the same because your filenames begin with the part of the string you want to use to sort. Same for your second filename format.

Comment: @chris - comparing numeric strings works sometimes.  I figured it was safer to parse into the actual time value which was only a few characters of extra code.

Comment: @jibcage - if your filenames are `2011-06-23-second-post.html` and are always consistently formatted like that with four digit years, two digit months and two digit days even when it's `2012-01-01`, then you can just compare the whole filenames without parsing the numbers.  Or, for more independence from formatting details, you could use the `Date()` class to actually parse the date into a number and compare the actual numbers.

Comment: @jibcage - As it looks like you're new here on stackoverflow, do you realize that you're supposed to vote for answers that help you (by clicking on the up arrow of any answer that is helpful to you) and ultimately pick one that answered your question by clicking the checkmark right under the number to the left of the answer?  This is part of people's incentive for helping you (they get points for providing a useful answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this in JavaScript however if you can sort your data server-side it would be appreciated by your users:

```
 $(function(){
   var jqXHR = [],//setup an array to store references to the `$.get()` jqXHR objects
       arr   = [],//setup an array to store the URLs and sort them numerically
       obj   = {};//setup an object o link URLs to HTML
   $.getJSON('helper.php', function(data) {
     $.each(data, function(key, val) {

       //add each `$.get()` request to our queue
       jqXHR.push($.get("articles/" + val, function(html){

             //add the URL to our array
             arr.push(val);

             //add the HTML to our object referenced by the URL
             obj[val] = html;
           }, 'html'));
     });

     //run the sort/append code after all the AJAX calls have been finished
     $.when(jqXHR).then(function () {

         //sort the array numerically descending
         arr.sort(function(a,b){

             //only sort by the numeric values in the URLs which should be everything before the first `-` character (hyphen)
             a = a.split('-')[0];
             b = b.split('-')[0];
             return b - a
         });

         //iterate through our array of sorted URLs and concoct them into a HTML string
         var len = arr.length,
             out = '';
         for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
             out += obj[arr[i]];
         }

         //append our HTML string to the DOM
         $("#postdata").append(out);
     });
   });
 });
```